# specify an email address for Google Calendar notifications via api

Tags: c#, email, google-api, google-calendar-api

How do I specify an email address for GoogleCalendar API notifications?

I need to programatically manipulate my Google Calendar via the Google API using C# dot-net.  I've been able to create, delete and modify events successfully, but I'd like some control over notifications. Currently only email and UI popup options are available, and email defaults to the Google email account.

What I'm thinking is that if I can manipulate the email address used, I can send email to my Verizon email-to-SMS address, and send a text message instead of email (SMS is an option only for Government accounts). Or possibly to a dummy email that interfaces to an SMS service like Twilio.  Bottom line is I would like to send email notifications to one or more email addresses of my choosing.

The only option for email is in a constructor for an EventReminder override:

```
new EventReminder{Method="email",Minutes=60};
```

Here's my working code:

```
namespace stuff
{
    class Program
    {
        static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };
        static string ApplicationName = "Google Calendar API .NET Quickstart";
        static string _Chelle = "fake_id@gmail.com";
        static string _EventCalendar = "jwejq36jjgwijg54iw7yjs7j7e@group.calendar.google.com";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Calendar API service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List(_EventCalendar);
            request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
            request.TimeMax = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
            request.ShowDeleted = false;
            Events events = request.Execute();
            if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
                {
                    // add new reminders
                    eventItem.Reminders = new Event.RemindersData
                    {
                        UseDefault = false,
                        Overrides = new[]
                        {
                            new EventReminder {Method="popup",Minutes=((60*24*7) - (60*9)) }, // one week before @ 0900
                            new EventReminder {Method="email",Minutes=((60*24*7) - (60*9)) }
                        }
                    };
                    try
                    {
                        service.Events.Update(eventItem, _EventCalendar, eventItem.Id).Execute();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No events found.");
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```